# POWERSHELL - Using an array with a Foreach loop, looking at users in an OU -

Tags: arrays, loops, powershell, foreach

Basicly i want to find inactive users so im using a foreach loop in a search base,

Now im trying to impliment looking at several OU's winthin an array at the start.

So this is what i was trying...

```
$OU=@("OU Path 1",
        "OU Path 2",
        "OU Path 3")

$OU | ForEach ($user in (Get-ADUser -SearchBase $_ -filter {(lastlogondate -notlike "*" -OR lastlogondate -le $90days) -AND (passwordlastset -le $90days) -AND (enabled -eq $True)} -Properties lastlogondate, passwordlastset | Select-Object name, lastlogondate, passwordlastset, samaccountname))
{

....
```

and getting the error....

> At line:18 char:22
>   + $OU | ForEach ($user in (Get-ADUser -SearchBase $_ -filter {(lastlogondate -notl ...
>   +                      ~~ Unexpected token 'in' in expression or statement. At line:18 char:21
>   + $OU | ForEach ($user in (Get-ADUser -SearchBase $_ -filter {(lastlogondate -notl ...
>   +                     ~ Missing closing ')' in expression. At line:18 char:293
>   + ... samaccountname))
>   +                    ~ Unexpected token ')' in expression or statement.
>       + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken

This Works Fine

```
$SearchBase1 = "OU1"
$SearchBase2 = "OU2"
$SearchBase3 = "OU3"


ForEach ($user in(Get-ADUser -SearchBase $SearchBase1 -filter {(lastlogondate -notlike "*" -OR lastlogondate -le $90days) -AND (passwordlastset -le $90days) -AND (enabled -eq $True)} -Properties lastlogondate, passwordlastset | Select-Object name, lastlogondate, passwordlastset, samaccountname))
{
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to created a nested ForEach loop, and forgot the first part of the loop. Here, you want to pipe `$OU` into a ForEach loop, and within that ForEach loop create another loop based on the current object of the first ForEach loop.

```
$OU | ForEach{
    ForEach ($user in (Get-ADUser -SearchBase $_ -filter {(lastlogondate -notlike "*" -OR lastlogondate -le $90days) -AND (passwordlastset -le $90days) -AND (enabled -eq $True)} -Properties lastlogondate, passwordlastset | Select-Object name, lastlogondate, passwordlastset, samaccountname))
    {
        <Do Stuff>
    } #End inner ForEach Loop for current OU
}
```